# How to remove a backslash from a character in R?

Tags: r, string, replace

I can't believe this is this hard.

```
t1 <- "1\2\3\4\5"
```

What won't work.

```
t1 <- gsub('\\','', t1)
t1 <- gsub('\\\\','', t1)
str_remove(t1, "\\")
str_remove(t1, "\\\\")
```

What also won't work:

1. Regex removing all non-alphanumeric characters. (This is an example, the text is more complicated than that - HTML/Javascript/SVG).

P.S: I did look at the other answers to similar questions on here and in the Berkley professor's book. Won't work.

Comment: "This is an example, the text is more complicated than that - HTML/Javascript/SVG" post your REAL text

Comment: @HongOoi - the "real" text is too long and adds no further value. Any html/js/svg file will do. This is the problem reduced to its minimum and it seems impossible to do in R. Which is disappointing. I know I could get around using regex, but I find that absurd. C#, Java, Python all can do this.

Comment: You don't have any backslashes in your text.

Comment: You probably also don't have any backslashes in your REAL text, which you haven't provided

Answer (score 1):

In fact, your second attempt with `gsub` is actually correct:

```
t1 <- gsub("\\\\", "", t1)
```

A literal backslash in regex requires *four* backslashes (two each for a literal backslash, one of which is required to escape the other backslash).  The reason the above appears to not work is that the string `t1` was defined incorrectly.  You should have defined it as:

```
t1 <- "1\\2\\3\\4\\5"
gsub("\\\\", "", t1)
[1] "12345"
```

A literal backslash in an R character literal requires *two* backslashes.  What you defined originally as `t1` is actually a bunch of control characters:

```
t1 <- "1\2\3\4\5"
```

Comment: Indeed I guess it may be useful to notice that OP's `t1` doesn't actually contain any backslash. It can be shown with `cat(t1)` (or using `charToRaw` and several other methods). On the other hand `cat(t1)` with your `t1` shows backslashes.

Comment: Tim,  I don't get to define the text. The text is given to me. What I think it means, I would have to use a different language or app to replace all "\" with some other "R friendly" character and process that "cleaner" file in R. I'm just going to use a different language all together then. What's mind boggling to me is that this seems impossible to do in R.